# why rabbitmq generate lots of idx file in queue directory

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, celery

I set up a RabbitMQ server with docker as below. then configure the celery to use it as broker.

```
rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        ports:
            - "5673:5672"

worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        links:
            - rabbit
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
```

And the celery configuration is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('test_celery',broker='amqp://admin:mypass@host:5673',backend='rpc://',include=['test_celery.tasks'])
```

Run_tasks code:

```
from .tasks import longtime_add
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = ['http://example1.com' , 'http://example2.com' , 'http://example3.com' , 'http://example4.com' , 'http://example5.com' , 'http://example6.com' , 'http://example7.com' , 'http://example8.com'] # change them to your ur list.
    for i in url:
        result = longtime_add.delay(i)
        print 'Task result:',result.result
```

tasks code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from test_celery.celery import app
import time,requests
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('10.1.1.234', 27018) # change the ip and port to your mongo database's
db = client.mongodb_test
collection = db.celery_test
post = db.test
@app.task(bind=True,default_retry_delay=10) # set a retry delay, 10 equal to 10s
def longtime_add(self,i):
    try:
        r = requests.get(i)
        if some conditions happend:
            longtime_add.delay(i)
        elif some other conditions happened:
            post.insert({'status':r.status_code,"creat_time":time.time()})             
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

The run_taks code will generate a list of url and send them to RabbitMQ, then tasks will consume them, and check some conditions happened or not, if happend send the result to Rabbtmq again , otherwise store the data to database.

The question here . When tasks run for a long time, 24 hours or even long, Lots of idx files will be generated in directory "mnesia/rabbit@rabbit/queues" by RabbitMQ . The total size will be 40G.

So the question here , how to stop these large file generated automatically or keeping in a small size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.idx files are queue index segments. Make your apps consume enqueued messages and [acknowledge them](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html), then queue indices will be updated and their segment files deleted when they are no longer necessary.

You can also purge or delete queues, of course.

Comment: The function I used above is the right way to consume tasks? Or how do I correct the code ?

Comment: See http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html and http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html if 
the difference isn't clear. 

I suspect that there may be a Celery worker that enqueues messages but they are never consumed. 
It should be quite easy to see in the management UI.